# Adding Kendo Controls on Kendo Scheduler Custom Template

Tags: kendo-ui, scheduler

I have a Kendo Scheduler in MVC Core, and I need to open the custom popup on click of the events on calendar. I am able to add the Script tag and give ID and Call the template as pop up by using that ID.

Issue I have is when I try to add the kendo control within script it fails. normal buttons and labels work fine. Moment I add the Kendo Button it fails.

Can someone help on this one

CODE:

```
<script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<h3>Edit meeting</h3>
<p>
    <label>Title: <input name="title" /></label>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Start: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="start" /></label>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Start: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="end" /></label>
</p>
```

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
editable: {
    template: $("#editor").html()
},
views: [
    { type: "day" }
],
dataSource: [
    {
        id: 1,
        start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
        end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
        title: "Interview"
    }
]
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You should either use [MVVM](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/overview) to create a [custom editor](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/how-to/editing/custom-edit-and-event-templates) or add an edit event handler, and when the event fires initialize a widget from a DOM element in the template. [Example](https://dojo.telerik.com/@AleksandarEvangelatov/edaBUvUG)